# Making changes to php.ini

Tags: php, date

I'm using [Mac OS X v10.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard). I'm a complete newbie to PHP. I was going through a tutorial and tried to run a date() function in my code, and I got a message that read "Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings..." and so on.

I read online that I have to make a change to my *php.ini* file, specifically the line of code mentioning *date.timezone*, so that it is set to the zone you want.

I checked the output of *phpinfo()* and found that in the directory */private/etc*, I have a php.ini.default file. This was the file I needed, albeit it had the extension ".default". I tried to make changes to it, but I was prevented from doing so, getting a warning stating that it was write-protected.

I copied this file to a new file called php.ini (using the terminal command `cp php.ini.default php.ini`). This new file was still write-protected though.

Just out of curiosity, I right clicked the */private* directory and hit "get info", and I saw that the folder was read-only.

So how should I go about making adjustments so that the *date()* function works? Should I create a *php.ini* file in another directory? Should I create a *php.ini* file in the same directory, and then physically copy and paste the contents from *php.ini.default*? I know my question might sound very foolish, but I'm a bit worried about making a destructive, long-lasting change.

Comment: This question is off topic here

Comment: You need to unlock the file so you can edit it. It's the little padlock icon at the bottom of "get info" - but this questions is offtopic here.

Comment: It does concern the date function, but it must be manipulated using the php.ini file. So the final objective was to make a change to the php.ini file, which I was unable to do. If you read my post carefully, you will see that that was my objective. It isn't off topic at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in your PHP script for example:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

If you need to change date.timezone globally in your */private/etc/php.ini* script, add

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Belgrade
```

Comment: hi pregmatch, the local command you provided worked in my php script perfectly. the issue with making a global change is: (1) In the /private/etc directory, there is a php.ini.default file, but no php.ini file and (2) This file is write-protected. Should I create a new file called php.ini in the same directory, and copy over the contents of php.ini.default to it? If so, how will the system recognize the new php.ini file? Thank you very much.

Comment: do this: 1) touch /private/etc/php.ini 2) cat /private/etc/php.ini.default > /private/etc/php.ini 3) open /private/etc/php.ini and find that date.timezone part and chnage it to your timezone. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: when i tried to do the cat command, it said "~bash: php.ini: Permission denied"

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. This is what I did: (1) Deactivate Web Sharing under System Preferences/Sharing. (2) Right-click php.ini.default, select Get Info, and changing read-only permission to read-write permission. (3) Copying over the file to php.ini by typing "sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini". (4)Changing the permission of php.ini to read-write as I did with php.ini.default (5) Change the date.timezone code in php.ini like you did above and save. (6) Reactivate Web Sharing. Doing all this, it worked globally. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

OS X is Unix underneath. `sudo mv php.ini.default php.ini` from your **terminal.app** should work. Don’t forgot switch `cd` to the directory.

To clarify, you don't need to switch protected to false. Since it is a configuration file which rarely get updated. `sudo vi php.ini` should let you override.

Comment: I originally did sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini from the terminal.app, and ran into the aforementioned problems. Would doing mv eliminate this?

Comment: @santhosh no, I didn't answer completely, I was suggesting to use `sudo` to override the permission issue. Updated my answer to be little more clear.